# Angular Material Row when looping through data

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-5, angular-material-table

My Data Source is like below

```
[{"isGroup":true,"groupName":"MV Reddy","items":[{"id":1,"name":"MV Reddy","verticalid":5,"vertical":"Colocation - Large > 20 Racks","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2019},{"id":10,"name":"MV Reddy","verticalid":6,"vertical":"Govt","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2020}]},{"isGroup":true,"groupName":"Neeraj Jha","items":[{"id":2,"name":"Neeraj Jha","verticalid":4,"vertical":"Alliances","target":"70","sap":"20","colo":"30","others":"20","quarter":2,"year":2019},{"id":5,"name":"Neeraj Jha","verticalid":4,"vertical":"Alliances","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2019}]},{"isGroup":false,"groupName":"Suresh Rathod","items":[{"id":3,"name":"Suresh Rathod","verticalid":3,"vertical":"C4C India (Public Cloud)","target":"100","sap":"20","colo":"30","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2019}]},{"isGroup":false,"groupName":"Arun Dubey","items":[{"id":4,"name":"Arun Dubey","verticalid":6,"vertical":"Govt","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":4,"year":2019}]},{"isGroup":true,"groupName":"Atin Singh","items":[{"id":6,"name":"Atin Singh","verticalid":5,"vertical":"Colocation - Large > 20 Racks","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2020},{"id":7,"name":"Atin Singh","verticalid":2,"vertical":"IAAS and Rest of Ctrls Services","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2020},{"id":8,"name":"Atin Singh","verticalid":3,"vertical":"C4C India (Public Cloud)","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2020},{"id":9,"name":"Atin Singh","verticalid":6,"vertical":"Govt","target":"150","sap":"80","colo":"20","others":"50","quarter":1,"year":2020}]}]
```

and I wrote/printing my Table like this:

```
<table class="mat-elevation-z8 " mat-table matSort [dataSource]='targetData' (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Employee">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.items[0].name}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="groupData">

        <ng-container *matCellDef="let group">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let groupCol of group.items;index as i;">
                <ng-container *ngIf="i==0 else newRow;">
                    <td mat-cell rowspan="group.items.length">
                        {{group.groupName}}
                    </td>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        {{groupCol.vertical}}
                    </td>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        {{groupCol.target}}
                    </td>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        {{groupCol.sap}}
                    </td>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        {{groupCol.colo}}
                    </td>
                    <td mat-cell>
                        {{groupCol.others}}
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-template #newRow>
                    <tr mat-row>
                        <td mat-cell>
                            {{groupCol.vertical}}
                        </td>
                        <td mat-cell>
                            {{groupCol.target}}
                        </td>
                        <td mat-cell>
                            {{groupCol.sap}}
                        </td>
                        <td mat-cell>
                            {{groupCol.colo}}
                        </td>
                        <td mat-cell>
                            {{groupCol.others}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>

            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>

    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Vertical">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vertical</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.items[0].vertical}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Target">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Target</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.items[0].target}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="SAP">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SAP</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.items[0].sap}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="COLO">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COLO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.items[0].colo}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Others">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Others</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.items[0].others}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <div class="tableActions ">

                <button class="view mat-button" (click)='edit(element.items[0])'>
                    <i class="material-icons">
                        create
                    </i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="TargetTable;"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: TargetTable;"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['groupData']; when: isAGroup"></tr>
</table>
```

I am unable to print another row inside a table while looping through my data

Final result should be like below.

[image: End Result should look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach goes in the right direction as you're using the `rowspan` attribute. The template however is unnecessary complex and can be simplified if you pre-process your data.

I solved a similar problem in the open source project [Koia](https://github.com/centeractive/koia) using a [RowSpanComputer](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/row-span-computer.ts) class. Within [summary-table.component.html](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/summary-table.component.html), the computed row spans are then used to define the `rowspan` attribute of the `td` element.

```
[attr.rowspan]="rowSpans[iCol][iRow].span"
```

The [RowSpanComputer](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/summary-table/row-span-computer.ts) class computes the `rowspan` for each cell out of the specified table data (array of rows). It basically loops over the rows and increments the `rowspan` for cells as long as their value remains unchanged and left located cells were also spanned. As soon as the value changes, the corresponding `rowspan` is reset to zero.

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3s8eat) that uses the data you provided. This must obviously further be refined in order to obtain the result you expect.

**UPDATE**

If you want to have `rowspan` applied for cells even if left located cells were not spanned, simply remove the following line from the `RowSpanComputer` class.

```
spanColumnContexts.slice(iCol + 1).forEach(c => c.spannedRow = {});
```

I did this in this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjtkqp) where a renamed `RowSpanComputer` to `GroupingRowSpanComputer` in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: if you can see, this is not printing data without Groups.

Comment: I updated my answer and provided another StackBlitz that hopefully does what you expected.

Comment: I dont see the non grouped ones in updated stackblitz. i solved it like below.

Comment: I explicitly filtered non-grouped items out because that's how I understood your request. Now I changed both StackBlitz and also include non-grouped items, please check again.

Comment: What you think of my answer below?

Comment: In your solution, same column values inside the same group are not combined. But if the result meets your expectations, its all fine.

Answer (score 0):

**My Table:**

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="targetData" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Employee">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.rowspan]="rowSpanLength(element)"
            [style.display]="rowSpanLength(element)>0 ? ''  : 'none'">
            {{element.name}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Vertical">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Vertical </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.vertical}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Target">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Target </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.target}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="SAP">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SAP </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sap}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="COLO">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> COLO </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.colo}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Others">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Others</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.others}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="TargetTableColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: TargetTableColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

And my **rowSpanLength** function like below:

```
rowSpanLength(item) {
    let nameArr = this.targetData.filter(i => i.name === item.name);
    //return length if the item is first element in above array else 0
    return nameArr[0].id === item.id ? nameArr.length : 0;
}
```

This function will keep rowSpan if the item/tr is first one from Group, for rest of all items the Name td will be hidden.

The result is like below which is what i wanted. got this idea from @uminder (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2358409/uminder) stackblitz
[image: Final Result Image]